# Python: How do I convert date to UK format when automating Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am automating my Excel (2016) workbook using Python (3.7.1). A cut down snippet of my code is below. The code prompts a user to input a date in UK format (dd/mm/yyyy). The problem is that when it updates the spreadsheet in Cell B8, it does so in US format (mm/dd/yyyy).

e.g. I enter 12/01/2022 (12 January 2022) and I get 01/12/2022 (1 December 2022).
The format of cell B8 is 'Date'.
If I try: type(uk_date_format) I get <class 'str'>
I am using a company machine and my regional setting are set to UK.
I am running my code via a cmd window on a Windows 10 machine.

Is there some way I can force it to a UK format? Any assistance would be great.

```
import os.path
import win32com.client

uk_date_format = input("Enter date in UK format e.g. dd/mm/yyyy:")
#I enter 12/01/2022 (12 January 2022)

file_path_and_name = "C:\\temp\\exampleFile.xlsb"
if os.path.exists(file_path_and_name):
    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
    xlsPath = os.path.expanduser(file_path_and_name)
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
    ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("B8").value = uk_date_format
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close(False)
    wb = None
    xlApp.Quit()
    xlApp = None
    print("All done")
```

This is what I get in Excel:
[image]

Comment: Documentation of this module is somewhat arcane, so I don't have a good answer yet, but could you try setting `NumberFormat` of the cell or Range? It might be something like `ws.Range("B8").number_format = "dd/mm/yyyy"` (I'm basing this assumption on the VBA model)

Comment: First thing to check is that Excel is displaying dates as you expect Enter `=TODAY()` in any cell, and see what Excel displays: does it appear as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy? If the latter, then despite what you think, your Excel is using the US date format. Even though your "Region" might be "United Kingdom", your "Regional Format" might be "English(United States)".

Answer (score 0):

I guess since you are inserting a raw string input rather a datetime object into your excel it shows up in the default (m/d/Y) format. You shall try this

```
import datetime.datetime
uk_date_format = input("Enter date in UK format e.g. dd/mm/yyyy:")
day, month,year = map(int, uk_date_format.split('/'))
ukdate = datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
ukdate=ukdate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(ukdate)
```

and replace

```
ws.Range("B8").value = uk_date_format
```

with

```
ws.Range("B8").value = ukdate
```

Hopefully that works

Comment: "UK" date is noit "%m-%d-%Y". Just USA uses the monstrosity of m/d/y . 
But regardless, entering a date won't solve the problem there, as it is excel's displaying of the date that is wrong. That has to be fixed by changing the cell formatting.

Comment: As alluded to in this answer, just set the cell value to be the datetime object. Excel will quite often try to be "helpful" by converting strings that look like dates into Excel's date type (double), and that can cause trouble. Once you have the correct underlying date in Excel you can then address the problem of why it is not being displayed as you want.